# SQL Drop View Statement Takes Forever to Complete

Tags: sql, ddl

I have a SQL Server 2008 R2 Enterprise database with a view on it called vw_Users.

-Running (Select * from vw_users) takes less than a second to complete.

-Running the SQL inside of the view takes less than a second to complete.

-Running (drop view vw_Users) just hangs and never actually completes.  I let it run for about 10 minutes before I cancelled it.

I restarted the SQL Server Agent, then tried again, but it's still occurring.

This is a brand new issue, this server and this database have been running fine for over a year.

There are no indices on the view.  I'm not sure what the problem is, but any help would be very appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 20):

**Someone or something has an open connection accessing that view and you are being blocked.**

You can check this by starting your `DROP`, then in another window in SSMS running:

`sp_who2 active`

You should see a row with your spid, and the `blocked_by` field will have another spid number in it.  Find that spid to see what is blocking you.

If it can be safely terminated, either close the process manually or from within SSMS run:

`kill x`

...where `x` is the spid of the blocking process.

Comment: For anyone else doing this; I followed this and found the SPID number that was blocking me but couldn't find it in the table. Just entering `sp_who2` provides a longer list which had the blocking SPID  for me

Comment: Excellent.  I was attempting to ALTER VIEW neglecting to realize a breakpoint in a related C# app was the culprit that blocked the ALTER VIEW operation.  The _ProgramName_ column gave the clue given the value _.Net SqlClient Data Provider._

Comment: Yep found out I was at a breakpoint in my C# app that was blocking any updates to this table.

Comment: Still hanging.  Having same problem, unable to alter or delete one particular view.  Restarted service.  The query window is the only interactive window all other spids background/sleeping.  Not jobs running either.  Finally, after restoring the database from backup its fine.